# String concatenation fails

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am learning the python and I encountered some new issue here. Can anyone explain this python code what exactly is happening internally.

```
>>> s="sam"
>>> s +="dam"
>>> s
'samdam'
>>> d +=s
>>> d
'msamdam'
>>> f = f+s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#129>", line 1, in <module>
    f = f+s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>> f +=s

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#130>", line 1, in <module>
    f +=s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: What is f in your code ?

Comment: Could you update your code to include the instanciations of d and f?

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that variable f is integer type and s is string. You can't concatenate integer and string that way. If you want to do this it should be like:

```
str(f) + s
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is an `integer` and `s` is a `string`. You cannot concatenate numbers and strings.

You can make it work by doing so:

```
x = str(f) + s
```

This will convert `f` to a string and then concatenate with `s`. For example, if `f` is `123`, `x` will be `123msamdam`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that f is an integer here, so maybe you can use :

```
f = str(f) + s
```

In this way, f will become a string.